# Создать сайт самому или ставить CMS?

Tags: html, cms, site

Собираюсь создать довольно простенький сайт с уроками по различным тематикам и стал перед вопросом, писать сайт с нуля или все же поставить CMS. Если логически подумать, то CMS будет оптимизированей твоего дизайна(ну конечно, тут зависит от твоих знаний и навыков, но я не скажу что могу написать вот так быстро полностью оптимизированный сайт) на разных устройствах и поставить/заполнять его будет проще. Но стоит ли этого? Или все же создавать свой дизайн и свою экосистему на сайте и любить ее до мелочей, со всеми ошибками? Опишите свой опыт работы и чтобы вы могли посоветовать.

Comment: под ваши цели существует куча CMS, например WordPress, зачем изобретать велосипед

Comment: Так речь о CMS или о дизайне? Никто не запрещает вкрутить собственный дизайн в любую существующую CMS. Аналогично никто не запрещает своровать чужие существующие дизайны в свою собственную CMS (если лицензиями разрешено).

Answer (score 5):

Если ваша цель наполнение ресурса информацией - устанавливайте CMS, иначе разработка займёт всё свободное время и до полезного содержимого вы дойдёте очень нескоро.

Если цель в освоении веб-программирования - пишите что-то своё, пройдётесь по всем граблям и наиграетесь вволю.

Answer (score 2):

Простенький сайт, где упор идет на содержание, естественно, лучше CMS и, как говорится, "не париться". Потому что разработка дизайна - дело основательное и трудоемкое. Кажется, что "ну чисто стили переписать", но разбираться со стилями в структуре тобою не организованной, может оказаться задачей даже сложнее, чем собственноручно написанный с нуля сайт.

Если это арт-объект (чем сайт с уроками не является по определению), то тут только собственная разработка, ИМХО.
Потому что будет своя структура, в которой ты будешь разбираться как рыба в воде и это-то и нужно при качественном дизайне и макетировании сайта как презентабельной площадки.

Если это будет формат блога, то рекомендую Jekyll. В нем можно и наиграться с дизайном, а функционал блога там вшит с корнем в движок. Но придется его изучить, недельку потратить, разобраться кто-чего...
К тому же он предоставляет статический контент (никаких баз данных), но это может быть и ограничением, мало информации о проекте предоставил.  Поэтому просто рекомендую погуглить о нем, посмотреть что умеет этот движок.

Answer (score 1):

Многое зависит от контента, например если вас удовлетворит какой-нибудь шаблон для cms и вам надо будет просто добавлять статьи и на этом все, то можно просто cms, в некоторых же случаях функционал будет избыточным и что то простое можно написать самостоятельно.
Для готовой cms, чтобы сменить цвет, передвинуть/добавить/поменять кнопку все равно придётся лезть в код. Хороший вариант, это когда  cms у вас отвечает просто за редактирование данных в БД, а вывод/отображение написано собственноручно, так, как вы хотите.